# Getting Akka actor self-reference difference

Tags: akka

I use Akka framework with Java API, so then I try to understand source code of framework - I can't, because it's written in Scala, unfortunately I don't know this language.
So, what is the difference between getting ActorRef pointing to self with `self()` and `getSelf()` method?

**UPDATE:** And what about context() and getContext()? I've noticed they return objects of different types within actor, extended from UntypedActor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self()` is the idiomatic scala API and `getSelf()` is the idiomatic Java API. They return the same value, but `getSelf()` is only accessible from subclasses of `UntypedActor` which is the class to be extended from Java to implement actors.

Comment: I suppose answer for update to question is related with "...is only accessible from subclasses of UntypedActor which is the class to be extended from Java to implement actors."?

Comment: This is the actual code:
```
def getContext(): UntypedActorContext = context.asInstanceOf[UntypedActorContext]
```
In other words, the context is exactly the same implementation underneath, it is adding some Java convenience interface.

Comment: Btw, it is quite usual to have Acala and Java versions for the same API in Akka. Usually there are markers in the javadocs saying JAVA API and SCALA API, but in older code these seem to be missing at a few places.

Comment: I should learn Scala core, it's becoming very interesting for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference: they point to the same final value.

Comment: Thank you, hope I will find a time to learn Scala so that I can understand source code of such a libraries like Akka.